# How can I apply a custom material design theme to a Bootstrap component

Tags: css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, material-design, angular-material

I'm using Angular Material design components to have a consistent look and feel through my entire website. [(Angular Material Design)](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/)

I created my custom theme for this:

```
        $mdThemingProvider.theme('default')
      .primaryPalette('red', {
          'default': '700',
          'hue-1': '100',
          'hue-2': '600',
          'hue-3': 'A100'
        })
      .accentPalette('light-blue');
```

Unfortunately, I cannot find the CSS to define a badge, therefore I used the one provided by bootstrap.
The problem with this is that my custom theme is not being applied.

How can I achieve this? Or, even better, does material design CSS provide something similar?(could not manage to find this).

This is what I have at the momement:
[image]

and the html for that is:

```
 <div class="md-block" layout layout-align="center center">
                        <div flex="20" layout layout-align="center center">
                            <span class="md-body-1">Poll interval in days</span>
                        </div>
                        <md-slider class="md-primary" flex ng-model="client.PollIntervalInDays" step="1" min="1" max="100" aria-label="rating">
                        </md-slider>
                        <div flex="20" layout layout-align="center center">
                            <h2><span class="label label-pill label-danger">{{client.PollIntervalInDays}}</span></h2>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

The problem is that the colors from **md-primary** does not match with **label-danger**. I tried applying the md-priamry on the span, but it does not work.

Any ideas?

Comment: Checkout https://github.com/tilwinjoy/angular-bootstrap-material

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do everything possible to not mix Bootstrap into an Angular Material site. The idea of having 2 CSS frameworks in play sounds like nothing but a hot mess to me.

Here's a codepen of a badge implemented in Angular Material: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/QbXwYq

They are doing it using a button and some CSS:

```
md-badge{
  margin: 0 0 0 8px;
  background-color: #259b24;
  color: white;
  padding: 2px 4px;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
.md-warn{
  background-color: #F44336;
}
```

I've also used a single, readonly md-chip to fake a badge and was OK with the results.